# INDEX and MATCH with VBA prints out formula with "@" and gives me error

Tags: excel, vba

So applying this formula:

```
=INDEX(Clientes!$G$2:$G$190;
MATCH(1;
('FormatoFazt'!A2 = Clientes!$C$2:$C$190)*('FormatoFazt'!F2 = Clientes!$D$2:$D$190)*('FormatoFazt'!T2 >= Clientes!$E$2:$E$190)*('FormatoFazt'!T2<=Clientes!$F$2:$F$190);0))
```

to over 50.000 rows was to slow in vba, so I decided to just copy and paste the formula on each cell. The problem is that when I do that, the formula is printed with an @ and gives me #N/D. If I take away the @ the formula works great.

I tried this:

```
Sub FastMatchIndexx()
    Dim wsClientes As Worksheet
    Dim wsFormatoFazt As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowG As Long, lastRowC As Long, lastRowD As Long, lastRowE As Long, lastRowF As Long
    Dim formulaPart As String

    Set wsClientes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clientes")
    Set wsFormatoFazt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FormatoFazt")

    lastRowG = wsClientes.Cells(wsClientes.Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowC = wsClientes.Cells(wsClientes.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowD = wsClientes.Cells(wsClientes.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowE = wsClientes.Cells(wsClientes.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowF = wsClientes.Cells(wsClientes.Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastRowFormatoFazt As Long
    lastRowFormatoFazt = wsFormatoFazt.Cells(wsFormatoFazt.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   
   formulaPart = "=INDEX(Clientes!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowG & ", MATCH(1, ('FormatoFazt'!A2 = Clientes!$C$2:$C$" & lastRowC & ")*('FormatoFazt'!F2 = Clientes!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowD & ")*('FormatoFazt'!T2 >= Clientes!$E$2:$E$" & lastRowE & ")*('FormatoFazt'!T2 <= Clientes!$F$2:$F$" & lastRowF & "), 0))"

    ' Aplicar la fórmula a las celdas necesarias en "FormatoFazt"
    wsFormatoFazt.Range("U2:U" & lastRowFormatoFazt).Formula = formulaPart
End Sub
```

And was expecting to get this printed on each cell:

```
=INDEX(Clientes!$G$2:$G$190; MATCH(1; (FormatoFazt!A2 = Clientes!$C$2:$C$190)*(FormatoFazt!F2 = Clientes!$D$2:$D$190)*(FormatoFazt!T2 >= Clientes!$E$2:$E$190)*(FormatoFazt!T2 <= Clientes!$F$2:$F$190); 0))
```

but insted i got this printed out:

```
=INDEX(Clientes!$G$2:$G$190; MATCH(1; (FormatoFazt!A2 =@ Clientes!$C$2:$C$190)*(FormatoFazt!F2 =@ Clientes!$D$2:$D$190)*(FormatoFazt!T2 >=@ Clientes!$E$2:$E$190)*(FormatoFazt!T2 <=@ Clientes!$F$2:$F$190); 0))
```

If I take out the @ the formula works great.

I aslo tried adding a "&" before the formula and then replacing with a "=", but it still prints as if it were text, so the formula dosent calculate, just gets printed out:

```
formulaPart = "&INDEX(Clientes!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowG & ", MATCH(1, ('FormatoFazt'!A2 = Clientes!$C$2:$C$" & lastRowC & ")*('FormatoFazt'!F2 = Clientes!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowD & ")*('FormatoFazt'!T2 >= Clientes!$E$2:$E$" & lastRowE & ")*('FormatoFazt'!T2 <= Clientes!$F$2:$F$" & lastRowF & "), 0))"

Set rangoU = wsFormatoFazt.Range("U2:U" & lastRowFormatoFazt)
    
     With rangoU
        .Replace What:="&", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
        .Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
    End With
```

Comment: Use `.Formula2` instead of `.Formula`

Comment: If you need to understand why that happens then go through these two links. [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)  and also see a post by @ScottCraner [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1525270/why-have-at-symbols-suddenly-appeared-in-my-excel-formulae)

Comment: BTW you have the same issue as mentioned in [don't want to automatically add "@" symbol in excel formula](https://superuser.com/questions/1778496/dont-want-to-automatically-add-symbol-in-excel-formula)